# Cómo hago para que los TextView se adapten a la fuente del telefono?

Tags: android, responsive, textview, font-size

El problema lo tengo en que al iniciar mi app en telefonos donde la gente ha aumentado el tamaño de la fuente bastante de lo normal, me salen todos los TextView superponiendose unos encima de otros, letras gigantes..todo bastante mal la verdad. Hay alguna manera para que esto se ajuste como si fuera responsive? O alguna manera de ignorar el aumento de tamaño de la fuente del dispositivo? Espero alguna respuesta gracias!!

Answer (score -1):

Yo resolvi este problema utilizando `Autosizing TextViews`. Si bien esta disponible a partir de una cierta version (28) tiene backwards compatibility, lo que significa que lo puedes utilizar en version anteriores ( A partir de 14).

El ejemplo básico es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

</LinearLayout>
```

La etiqueta `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` permite realizar esta acción, con solo agregarle esta propiedad se ajusta a uniformemente a las dimensiones que horizontales y verticales del textview.

En algunos casos no es suficiente, entonces puedes agregarle un poco más de detalle como el siguiente.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />
```

- la etiqueta `android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"` te permite definir cual es el **mínimo** tamaño que tu textview puede tener cuando se haga el resize.
- la etiqueta `android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"` te permite definir cual es el **máximo** tamaño que tu textview puede tomar cuando se haga el resize.
- la etiqueta `android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"` indica como aumentar o reducir el size uniformemente, es decir si en un momento el actual size es 20sp, y se reduce el espacio entonces el textview tendrá que reducir su espacio, para esto como le seseamos la granularidad como 2sp, entonces el textview reducirá su tamaño a 18sp. De manera contraria si tiene más espacio entonces el textview sabe que puede aumentar su tamaño, por lo tanto tendrá 22sp de tamaño.

De todas maneras te dejo algunas referencias si quieres estudiar a más detalle :

- [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)
- [Medium](https://medium.com/over-engineering/making-the-most-of-textview-auto-sizing-on-android-a39f71b6f3af)
- [Raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7930-autosizing-textview-tutorial-for-android-getting-started)

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!! La verdad que es bastante útil el uso del autosize, pero me he fijado que gastando dp y no sp en el textsize las fuentes se quedan como están y se agradece bastante, ya que no se desconjunta nada de la app. Al final en una app es muy complicado cuadrar todos los tamaños de las letras y unos quedan diferente a los otros...creo que vale la pena dejarlo todo fijo sin los pixeles escalables.

Comment: Creo que puedes agregarle "sp" al textSize si calculas bien el autoSizeMinTextSize y autoSizeMaxTextSize, seria cuestión de evaluar el diseño que tienes, pero concuerdo contigo que en muchas ocasiones cuadrar  todos los componentes se complica demasiado :( . Saludos :)